# Schema for Books, Magazines, other forms of media

Tags: xml, xsd, media

I am going to be working on a project that will heavily involve indexing various forms of media including Books, Magazines, Web sites / pages, etc.

What I am wondering is if there is a standard schema, xml, dtd, object model, database model, etc that anyone knows about and can point me to as a starting point or reference

I greatly appreciate any knowledge you can share,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dublin core.  google it or wikipedia it.

wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure whether this is any help for you:

The last time I worked with this kind of data I stumbled over the existence of Document Oriented Databases (like Amazon SimpleDB) [Wikipedia on DOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database). Read it and decide for yourself. It made my life a lot easier.